# Why Algorithms with logarithmic time are considered to be fast?

Tags: algorithm

My knowledge of big-O notation is limited , but I read in some posts that algorithms with logarithmic time are fast , can someone explain it please .

Comment: There are many resources on this topic. Have you tried a simple search? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Logarithmic_time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add-on to what willyonka said, here is a graph:

[image: Log(n) scales much better than most algorithms]

See [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o)

Answer (score 3):

For large N, the *percentage* of saved operations compared to linear equivalents grows rapidly. As the gradient of a log(N) is proportional to 1/N, for large N O(NlogN) behaves more like O(N) than O(N^2) - for this reason they are often called "linearithmic" or "quasi-linear".